# plugin not loading my css and js

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Hi I'm using the standard way to load styles and scripts within my plugin. But I have no clue why it's not working. It's not shown in the network tab nor in the `<head>`. Can this cause issues when overriding templates?

```php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles_scripts');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_styles_scripts');

function add_styles_scripts()
    wp_enqueue_style('rs_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'style/default.css', array());
    wp_enqueue_style('rs_fullscreen_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'style/fullscreen.css', array());
    wp_enqueue_script('rs_js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'style/default.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('rs_js', 'wordpress_data', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'render_custom_template' );

function render_custom_template( $template )
{
    add_styles_scripts();
```

Comment: which file is this in? Have you verified directly that the `add_styles_scripts` function runs via the error log breakpoints or a `wp_die`? Is the file this code is in also the root plugin file with the plugin header comment at the top? Or is it a different file? What does the rest of `render_custom_template` contain, and are you calling the necessary functions in that template such as `wp_head()` etc?

Comment: For reference, as long as your template is well built then all things that happen in the header should happen in the header. Using `template_include` wouldn't cause this, it's more likely to be a problem with running the code to enqueue, getting the right file enqueued, or not calling the necessary mandatory functions in the template ( aka WP knows what to enqueue but never has the opportunity to do it )

Comment: Your code works. Are you sure you have included the code file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was really easy. The template I was trying to load, did not have wp_head() in it. So ofcourse no JS/CSS was loading in. Thanks for the help everyone!